# How to find Runtime exceptions in android?

Tags: java, android

These are few bunch of text from LogCat.. i am not able to find out where is the Exception

> 07-06 04:03:55.933: D/dalvikvm(16700): open_cached_dex_file :
>   /mnt/asec/com.database-1/pkg.apk
>   /data/dalvik-cache/mnt@asec@com.database-1@pkg.apk@classes.dex 07-06
>   04:03:55.943: D/dalvikvm(16700): NOTE: loadClass
>   'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable' 0x4127ce20 threw exception
>   Ljava/lang/ClassNotFoundException; 07-06 04:03:55.943:
>   W/dalvikvm(16700): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1559
>   (ActionBarWindow) in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; 07-06
>   04:03:55.944: D/dalvikvm(16700): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
>   07-06 04:03:55.947: D/AndroidRuntime(16700): Shutting down VM 07-06
>   04:03:55.947: W/dalvikvm(16700): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x40fa09a8) 07-06 04:03:55.948:
>   E/test(16700): Exception 07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main 07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable 07-06 04:03:55.949:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
>   07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
>   07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
>   07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   com.database.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 07-06
>   04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5182) 07-06
>   04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1081)
>   07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
>   07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>   07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156) 07-06
>   04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
>   07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 07-06
>   04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 07-06 04:03:55.949:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 07-06
>   04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-06
>   04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 07-06 04:03:55.949:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>   07-06 04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 07-06
>   04:03:55.949: E/AndroidRuntime(16700):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please help me how to solve this issue...

Comment: It would help if you'd provide us with _MainActivity.java_ code also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the v7 compat library is not configured correctly as seen in the log

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable"

If you are using Eclipse, Go to package explorer, right click on project and Android Tools > Add Support Library. After that clean and build your project.

Hope this resolves your error!